# Getting confused about taking multiple strings in a for loop

Tags: java

I was writing a code for taking multple strings as input and storing them in an Array like below:

```
int NumberOfTC=scanner.nextInt();
    String[] words=new String[NumberOfTC];
    for(int i=0;i<NumberOfTC;i++){
        words[i]=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(words[i]);
                  
    }
```

But this allows a single input string

After much inspection i see that the below code works:

```
System.out.print("No of Strings to Enter: ");
    int num = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    String[] words = new String[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
        words[i] = scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

I am not able to decode what is the use of scanner.nextLine() after the scanner.nextInt() line. I mean why my earlier code is not working and prints only a single string whereas the second code works properly

Comment: Scanner.nextLine is a blocking method, that means that until the input is not given the program will wait for it. I think that the first program worked as well but there weren't an indication because you didn't printed some text like please enter string.

Comment: Yes the first snippet also worked but strangely it printed a single string and did not wait for the second string to be entered.

Comment: Did you tried to type and enter or the program finished the run? I am not sure that the program finished the run

Comment: Why are you using two scanners in the first program? I ran it using a single instance and it works fine.